# C# detect Window Shutdown

Tags: c#, windows, events, system-shutdown

I want my C# Service to perform some tasks before a Windows shutdown.  I see that there is an event [SystemEvents.SessionEnding Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx). However it does not seem to distinguish between a logoff and a system shutdown. Anyone know of a way of detecting a shutdown? Thanks.

This is not a duplicate of the following question since I am specifically referencing Shutdown not Shutdown|Logoff:
[How to detect Windows shutdown or logoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799955/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Windows shutdown or logoff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799955/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff)

Comment: System shutdown is *not* the time to start doing work. (Most especially because you never get advanced notification of a power cut)

Comment: There is a more suitable event to acces via WPF but as Damien says, its morerly irelevant to start work there.

Comment: I agree to my previous commentators. However a lock can be a point where you want to do stuff. I myself had a use case where something had to happen when a user locks the pc ( automated logoff after a time ).

When the system shuts down he won't be happy about you starting stuff since it can prevent shutdown and/or slow it down. Also it could be that windows doesn't care and just shuts down without you being finished. Maybe explain the use case, so we can suggesst better approaches.

Comment: Basically I want my service to send a WCF message to a server when the system is shutting down. Looks like I cannot distinguish between a shutdown or a logoff?

Comment: It is possible to distinguish with Hex codes that are sent by windows internally when performing one of those actions.
The codes are listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868(v=vs.85).aspx

A stackOverflow question which already uses and processes these is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726116/when-using-exitwindowsex-logoff-works-but-shutdown-and-restart-do-not

He uses it to perform these actions though, in Order to catch them you have to catch https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Are you really implementing a Windows service? Services are stopped when the system shuts down and you even get some time to do a bit of work before Windows will give up on your service and just shut down anyway.

Comment: @MartinLiversage sounds like a service to me. Informing a server when a pc is shut down would best be done by a service that runs in the background does nothing than wait for the event. If you know a better solution I would love to hear it since I plan to use a service for an use case close to this :)

Comment: @Nico: The solution is to react to the shutdown event of your service. In .NET you do this by overriding the [`ServiceBase.OnShutdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx) method (or you can use a library like [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/).) And the mention of logging off in the question makes me think that perhaps this question is not about a service but about a desktop app running when the user is logged on.